# ImportError: No module named persistence.backends.sql

Tags: openstack, keystone

I am currently working on setting up OpenStack infrastructure on 3 nodes. I am stuck on starting keystone after I have successfully installed it. The error message I am getting is

```
ImportError: No module named persistence.backends.sql
```

The controller node has Ubuntu 12.04 and I am installing OpenStack icehouse version.. Could somebody shed some light on this error?

Comment: Also getting a similar error. Here is the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get that error if you used a keystone configuration file edited for the OpenStack Juno release with your Icehouse packages. In Icehouse, the correct value was "keystone.token.backends.sql.Token", only in Juno did it become "keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token". [1]

So, check your keystone.conf, make sure it is written for Icehouse.

[1] http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/keystone-conf-changes-juno.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Openstack Juno and the distro. you use is Ubuntu 14.04 just modify this line in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf

```
[token]
driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
```

To

```
driver = keystone.token.backends.sql.Token
```